# Why do I get a module has no attribute __main__ in ipython parallel gather statement?

Tags: python, ssh, ipython-parallel, dill

This is a related question to this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596463/why-do-i-get-a-cannedarray-object-has-no-attribute-pickled-in-ipython-gather

The difference is that now I'm trying to `use_dill` in ipython parallel and when I try to pull data it gives me an error. I have no idea if the data is ever `push`ed.

```
dv['a'] = 1
dv['a'] # <- this gives an error
```

The error I get is:

```
*** CompositeError: one or more exceptions from call to method: _pull
[0:apply]: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__main__'
[1:apply]: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__main__'
[2:apply]: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__main__'
[3:apply]: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__main__'
.... 9 more exceptions ...
```

I have no idea what is going on, any help is much appreciated.

If you want more info please let me know and I'll add it.

Thank you

Comment: Can you `dill.copy` (or `dill.dump` then `dill.load`) your object successfully?  Can you give an example of your data and function you are trying to serialize?